# WSO APIM 2.1 - Clustered - Why still needing a H2 local database?

Tags: datasource, wso2-api-manager

after a long and exhaustive time trying and trying to cluster the WSO2 API Management version 2.1.0 we´ve concluded the task using Postgree as database to keep all information about environment and usage statistics.

I noticed that even configuring all datasources as described in the guide https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment the WSO2 needs to a datasource named WSO2_CARBON_DB (jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB) that is recommended not to change and in this case I kept it point to a local H2 database.

The problem is that local database is increasing the size and I really have not ideia the usage for it.

Does somebody know how to remove this datasource or if pointing to external database (in a cluster environment) will create any issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the datasource to external DB by changing the configuration under repository/conf/datasources .I have implemented clustering using Oracle DB and worked as expected

Comment: We changed other datasources also, and worked fine.but WSO2 implicitly inform to don´t change a specific one. I´ve tried to change this datasource (WSO2_CARBON_DB) and worked fine, but is this correct ? What are the risks of changing this datasource ?

Comment: Wso2 recommend to use database other than h2 you can check in the production guideline https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Production+Deployment+Guidelines